# VBA - Build a Two-Column Array By Looping Through one Array with a Specific Criteria and Selecting From Another Array

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel data table looks like the one below:

```
Column1  Column 2
3        Blank
5        Blank
Blank    234
0        Blank
2        Blank
8        Blank
9        Blank
Blank    567
Blank    567
0        Blank
5        Blank
3        Blank
4        Blank
Blank    860
6        Blank
Blank    869
0        Blank
6        Blank
7        Blank
```

"Blank" means that the cell is empty.
In the table, "0" is my anchor. I want to look through Column 1 and match the last number above "0" with the number in Column 2 that is above "0".
For example, relating to the first 0 in Column 1, I want to match "234" with "5" in two separate output columns on the same row.
My final data set should look like:

```
Column 3   Column 4 
5          234
9          567
6          869
```

I have some code but it addresses only Column 1, with no blanks. It is not even close. Thanks!

```
Sub Cat()
   
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the 2nd source cell.
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = ws.Range("V12").Offset(1)
    
    ' Reference the 1st destinatin cell.
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = ws.Range("X12")
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(sCell.Value)
        If sCell.Value = 0 Then
            dCell.Value = sCell.Offset(-1).Value ' ... = previous source cell
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1) ' ... = next destination cell
        End If
        Set sCell = sCell.Offset(1) ' ... = next source cell
    Loop
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Loop over Col 1. If Value <> Blank and <> 0, store value in Variable A. If Value = Blank, store the value of Col 2 (same row) in variable B. If value = 0, write Var A and B into the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return Values Above Matching Cells

[image]

```vb
Sub Cat()
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "C2"
    Const DST_FIRST_RETURN_CELL As String = "D2"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim slrg As Range
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL)
        Set slrg = ws.Range(.Cells, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COLUMN)
    
    Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = ws.Range(DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL)
    Dim drCell As Range: Set drCell = ws.Range(DST_FIRST_RETURN_CELL)
    
    Dim slCell As Range, srCell As Range, lVal, rVal
    Dim r As Long, lNum As Double, rNum As Double
    
    For Each slCell In slrg.Cells
        lVal = slCell.Value
        r = r + 1
        Set srCell = srrg.Cells(r)
        rVal = srCell.Value
        If VarType(lVal) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            If lVal = 0 Then
                dlCell.Value = lNum: Set dlCell = dlCell.Offset(1)
                drCell.Value = rNum: Set drCell = drCell.Offset(1)
            End If
            lNum = lVal
        End If
        If VarType(rVal) = vbDouble Then rNum = rVal ' is a number
    Next slCell
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This code is legit but it was not working on my sheet, it was showing zeros in Column 4. I just realized the issue. In Column 2, I actually have text, not numbers. I now need to edit so that it does not only look for values.

Comment: Maybe declare `rNum` `As Variant` or `As String` and change the check like this: `If Len(CStr(rVal)) > 0 Then rNum = rVal ' is not blank`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned as comment: Loop over the cells of the source column. You can have 3 cases:

- The cell *is* empty: Save the value of the cell to the right in a variable - I named that `b`.
- The cell *is not* empty and not equal 0: Save this value in a second variable - I name it `a`
- The cell = 0: Dump the values of `a` and `b` to the destination.

Of course you should give the variables better names, depending on your business case.

You shouldn't check if the cell is empty as end criteria because that would end your loop at the firs empty cell of the first column. I use `CurrentRegion`, most likely that is good enough for your case.

If I where you, I would use Named Ranges instead of hardcoding the addresses into the code (it makes me shudder when I see something like `Range("V12")` hardcoded - Adding a row or a column to the sheet would break the code.

```
Sub Cat()
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  ' Or whatever your sheet is.
    
    Dim sCell As Range, dCell As Range
    Set dCell = ws.Range("X12")
    For Each sCell In ws.Range("V12").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
        Dim a as Variant, b as Variant
        If IsEmpty(sCell.Value) Then
            b = sCell.Offset(0, 1).Value    ' Cell to the right.
        ElseIf sCell.Value <> 0 Then
            a = sCell.Value
        Else
            dCell.Value = a                 ' Dump a...
            dCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = b    ' ...and b to the destination
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1, 0)  ' Move to next row
        End If
    Next sCell
    
End Sub
```